# how to implement search box in my application in android?

Tags: android

i have one activity in my android application in which a list of orders is populated. I want to implement a search functionality on this activity so that user can search for particular order.

I have read about the search box facility provided by adding a `searchable.xml` file in the application but I am not able to make it work for me?

I just want to add a search box in the activity and search for specific data in database.
How can I do this?

Comment: *but i am not able to invoke the search that way?* why? what error do you get? what can't you do?

Comment: i invoke the activity via the onSearchRequested() method. it returns true but no search dialog box appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@VNVN  I would agree - I would review the developer guide.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

You will need to make your activity search-able in the AndroidMainfest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".MySearchableActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing creating a SearchableActivity. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchableActivity